# Spring boot JPA Entity lifecycle events

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I need to check if current tenant is updating it's own entities and have used the `@PreUpdate` annotation. If i pass the full object `repository.save()` method I get the necessary `tenantId`, but once I pass `DTO` (mapped to entity by mapper) the `tenantId` is null. Since the `@SelectBeforeUpdate` is enabled shouldn't the field be mapped? The `@PreRemove` annotation is working fine and I get said property even though I only use an ID (`repository.remove(ID)`). I have also tried using the `@PostUpdate` method (since the `tenantId` is not updatable) but it still gives the null value. Can I perform the necessary check inside those events or is there some other solution (I'd like to keep service layer clean).

```
@PreRemove
public void preRemove() {
    //tenantId is not null
    if (Boolean.FALSE.equals(Objects.equals(tenantId, ThreadLocalStorage.getTenantId())))
        throw new EntityNotFoundException(id.toString(), this.getClass().getSimpleName());
}

@PreUpdate
public void preUpdate() {
    //tenantId is null
    if (Boolean.FALSE.equals(Objects.equals(tenantId, ThreadLocalStorage.getTenantId())))
        throw new EntityNotFoundException(id.toString(), this.getClass().getSimpleName());
}
```

Comment: I assume that SelectBeforeUpdate comes after preUpdate.

Answer (score 0):

Check it in a `@PostUpdate` listener. If you throw an exception anyway, you will abort the transaction through that mechanism anyway.

Comment: The problem is it always throws an exception since entity's `tenantId` is null. In order for that to work I would have to pass full entity every time.

Comment: If you use select-before-update anyway, why can't you use `repository.findById`, apply the changes on that object and be done?

Comment: As I said, I would like to avoid performing check on the service layer.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "service layer" here, but the "check" could reside in the entity as lifecycle listener.